# Rails app with no databse and continually updated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, soap

I'm wondering what the best way to go about developing a rails application with the following features:

- All of the data comes from a SOAP request to a 3rd party
- A background task will make this soap request every ~10s
- The background task will parse the response and then update an ActiveRecord model accordingly
- The data isn't written to a database at all, if the app fails, when we start it back up the data will come from the soap request again
- Users will make a request to the app which will simply show data in the model (i.e. from the soap request).

The idea is to avoid making the SOAP request for every single user as the data won't change that frequently. Not using a database avoids reading and writing of data that only ever comes from the request anyway.

I imagine that all of this can be completely quite simply with a few gems but I've had a bit of trouble sorting through what meets my requirements and what doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: What about using memcache instead of activerecord ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what benefit you're getting from using ActiveRecord in this case.

Perhaps consider some other type of persistance for the SOAP calls?

Comment: The benefit of using ActiveRecord is that I can then use all of the built in functions to generate reports using various queries.

Answer (score 1):

If the results form the WebService are really not changing, I would recommend the Rails caching mechanism. Wherever in your Rails app, you can do:

```
Rails.cache.fetch "a_unique_cache_key" do
  ... do your SOAP request and return the result
end
```

This will do the work within the block just once and fetch its result from the rails cache store in the future.

The cache store be of various types (one of which is the memcache store). I usually go with the file store for medium traffic sites, but you may choose another:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the data does fairly frequently (not exactly lots of load, maybe 4 or 5 times in a minute). The fact that the data changes and that we don't care about historical data are the 2 reasons for not using a DB.